# How to determine if variable is a Cheerio object?

Tags: cheerio

How do you tell if something is a loaded cheerio object? For instance:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const html = '<div>';
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const $div = $('div');

// if isCheerio func existed..    
if (cheerio.isCheerio(html)) {} // return false
if (cheerio.isCheerio($)) {} // return true
if (cheerio.isCheerio($div)) {} // return true
```

I could just check the typeof for a string vs func, but that is just a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const html = '<div>';
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const $div = $('div');

console.log(html.cheerio) // undefined
console.log($.cheerio) // undefined
console.log($().cheerio) // [cheerio object]
console.log($div.cheerio) // [cheerio object]
```

So you can then use these in conditionals, like:

```
if ($div.cheerio) {
  console.log($div.get())
}
```